# Hiding an MKMapView while Overlays Visible

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm am writing an iPhone app in which I overlay a custom image as a map on top of an `MKMapView`. The image is an `MKOverlayView`, and I would like to know if there is a way to hide or cover the underlying Google map up so the user never sees it when scrolling out bounds of my custom map. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: MKMapView is no googlemap  on os 6+ -- just FYI

Comment: updated the question for Apple-maps

Answer (score 3):

On iOS 6, the following sets the alpha channel of the map tiles to 0 (or 1) depending on the *show* flag.

**Note** that this method assumes a certain way in which these tiles are ordered. If Apple decides to change the inner workings of MKMapView in an iOS update, this method may break.

```
if ( [mapView.subviews count] &&
     [((UIView *)[mapView.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).subviews count] ) {
    ((UIView *)[((UIView *)[mapView.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).subviews objectAtIndex:0]).alpha = show ? 1.0 : 0.0;
}
```

Credits go here: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/84694-how-to-use-mapkit-without-maps.html

Answer (score 3):

`MKTileOverlay` has a `canReplaceMapContent` property. Set this to YES to tell the `MKMapView` not to draw its own tile underneath your overlay.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKTileOverlay_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Umm, I did include the essential parts. Set your overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
I pretty much did exactly what you just said to do...

Comment: @Pawan: Looks OK to me.  If the answer is wrong, explain why in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I will sugest you can draw a very big polygon with the the help of MKOverlay above the google map and try to overlay your custom map above it so that the google map will be hidden by the the very big polygon and your custom maps and annotations will be present.

It may not be a good idea. But its a trick that can workout.

Comment: So the issue here is that using MKOverlay still takes significant time to draw to the screen. During this time, the user can usually see the underlying Google map - What I would like is to prevent the user from ever seeing it in the first place.

Comment: When you are using MKMapView your are under Google Earth Api terms and conditions, so there is no chance of hiding, removing or stoping the Map being loaded from Google earth. You will not be able to find any property in MapKit to disable the maps being loaded.